# How to find gradient of the function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, vector-analysis

$x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
How to find gradient of $f(x) = -e^{-x^Tx}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-x^Tx = -(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)$$

$$-e^{-x^Tx} = -e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)}$$

$$\frac{\partial(-e^{-x^Tx})}{\partial x_i} = 2x_ie^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)} = 2x_ie^{-x^Tx}$$

Comment: You left out the "$-$" signs in $-e^{-x^Tx}$. Otherwise, you;ve got the right idea.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I didnt even notice minus signs. needd to go to bed it seems

Comment: Chains:  Well, you got it now!  ***endorsed, +1!!!***

Comment: @RobertLewis thanks!